# Create CSS HTML5 drop down navigation

Tags: html, css

I have this code for the navigation

```
        <div id="navigation">
        <a href="/">Home</a>
        <a href="index.php?sida=link2">link2</a>
        <a href="index.php?sida=lin3">link3</a>
        <a href="index.php?sida=link4">link4</a>
        <a href="index.php?sida=link5">link5</a>
        <a href="index.php?sida=link6">link6</a>
        <a href="index.php?sida=link7">Link7</a>
        </div>
```

This is the css for the Navigation

```
#navigation {
float: left;
height: 61px;
width: 885px;
background: url(../../../../images/navigation.png) no-repeat;
padding: 0 0 0 12px;
```

}

```
#navigation a {
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
float: left;
display: block;
height: 29px;
padding: 11px 30px 0 32px;
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 10px 0 0 0;
```

}

```
#navigation a:hover {
background: url(../../../../images/navigation_over.png) repeat-x;
```

}

```
#navigation a:hover.dropdown {
background: url(../../../../images/navigation_drop.gif) repeat-x;
```

}

I have been trying to learn how to create the drop down menu for my navigation, but without success.

Is there someone who is so kind to help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I creating dropdown menus with this css: (old enough and worked everywhere for me)

```
.vmenu {
list-style:none;
height:75%;
min-height:24px;
width:16.67%;
max-width:544px;
min-width:90px;
text-align:center;
float:left;
z-index:1;
}
.vmenu > li {
width:100%;
list-style:none;
}
.vmenu > a {
background-color:#FFAF00;
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
}
.vmenu li > a {
background-color:#FF9F00;
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
}
.vmenu > li {
display:none;
}
.vmenu:hover > li {
display:block;
}
.vmenu > a:focus~li {
display:block;
}
/* with CSS4 which is not yes supported by any browser
it has to be handled with javascript somehow
selects the li instead of a:focus to let the tab go through
.vmenu > $li > a:focus {
display:block;
}
*/
.vmenu li > a:hover {
background-color: #2580FF;
color:#DDDDDD;
}
.vmenu li > a:focus {
background-color: #2580FF;
color:#DDDDDD;
}
.vmenu > a:hover {
background-color: #258072;
color:#DDDDDD;
}
.vmenu > a:focus {
background-color: #258072;
color:#DDDDDD;
}
.vmenu > li > ul.vmenu {
width:100%;
display:none;
}
.vmenu:hover > li > ul.vmenu {
display:block;
}
.vmenu > a:focus~li > ul.vmenu {
display:block;
}
.vmenu > li > ul.vmenu > li {
display:none;
padding:0px 0px 0px 100%;
}
.vmenu li ul.vmenu > a {
background-color:#FFAF0F;
float:left;
}
.vmenu li ul.vmenu:hover > a {
background-color:#258072;
color:#DDDDDD;
}
.vmenu li ul.vmenu > a:focus {
background-color:#258072;
color:#DDDDDD;
}
.vmenu > li > ul.vmenu:hover > li {
top:0;
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
}
.vmenu > li > ul.vmenu > a:focus~li {
top:0;
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
}
/* with CSS4 which is not yes supported by any browser
it has to be handled with javascript somehow
selects the li instead of a:focus to let the tab go through
.vmenu > li > ul.vmenu > $li > a:focus {
top:0;
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

with fully nested submenus and partially supports keyboard navigation. see: comments in css

Example html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
* {
border-spacing:0px;
border:none;
height:inherit;
width:inherit;
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
}
body {
width:90%;
max-width:1600px;
min-width:800px;
margin:auto;
}
body > div {
width:100%;
}
.vmenu {
list-style:none;
height:75%;
min-height:24px;
width:16.67%;
max-width:544px;
min-width:90px;
text-align:center;
float:left;
z-index:1;
}
.vmenu > li {
width:100%;
list-style:none;
}
.vmenu > a {
background-color:#FFAF00;
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
}
.vmenu li > a {
background-color:#FF9F00;
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
}
.vmenu > li {
display:none;
}
.vmenu:hover > li {
display:block;
}
.vmenu > a:focus~li {
display:block;
}
/* with CSS4 which is not yes supported by any browser
it has to be handled with javascript somehow
selects the li instead of a:focus to let the tab go through
.vmenu > $li > a:focus {
display:block;
}
*/
.vmenu li > a:hover {
background-color: #2580FF;
color:#DDDDDD;
}
.vmenu li > a:focus {
background-color: #2580FF;
color:#DDDDDD;
}
.vmenu > a:hover {
background-color: #258072;
color:#DDDDDD;
}
.vmenu > a:focus {
background-color: #258072;
color:#DDDDDD;
}
.vmenu > li > ul.vmenu {
width:100%;
display:none;
}
.vmenu:hover > li > ul.vmenu {
display:block;
}
.vmenu > a:focus~li > ul.vmenu {
display:block;
}
.vmenu > li > ul.vmenu > li {
display:none;
padding:0px 0px 0px 100%;
}
.vmenu li ul.vmenu > a {
background-color:#FFAF0F;
float:left;
}
.vmenu li ul.vmenu:hover > a {
background-color:#258072;
color:#DDDDDD;
}
.vmenu li ul.vmenu > a:focus {
background-color:#258072;
color:#DDDDDD;
}
.vmenu > li > ul.vmenu:hover > li {
top:0;
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
}
.vmenu > li > ul.vmenu > a:focus~li {
top:0;
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
}
/* with CSS4 which is not yes supported by any browser
it has to be handled with javascript somehow
selects the li instead of a:focus to let the tab go through
.vmenu > li > ul.vmenu > $li > a:focus {
top:0;
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
}
*/
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <ul class="vmenu"><a href="">Menu1</a>
                <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item5</a></li>
                <li>
                    <ul class="vmenu"><a href="">SubMenu1</a>
                        <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ul class="vmenu"><a href="">SubMenu2</a>
                        <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item5</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <ul class="vmenu"><a href="">SubMenu1</a>
                                <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Item4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Item5</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="vmenu"><a href="">Menu2</a>
                <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item5</a></li>
                <li>
                    <ul class="vmenu"><a href="">SubMenu1</a>
                        <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ul class="vmenu"><a href="">SubMenu2</a>
                        <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Item5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

... it needs some work from you on z-index and colors to make it look better.

Answer (score 1):

Demo of Drop down ***[navigation](http://jsfiddle.net/3qPbE/18/)***

Hi if you created a navigation drop-down in `css`

do this

as like this

**HTML code**

```
<ul id="navi">
    <li><a href="" class="active">LInk 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">LInk 2</a>
        <ul class="subnavi">
            <li><a href="">LInk 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">LInk 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">LInk 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">LInk 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">LInk 1</a></li>    
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="">LInk 3</a></li>

    <div class="cl"></div>
</ul>
```

**Css Code**

```
.cl{clear:both;}
#navi{
    background:#0082c8;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:15px;
}


#navi > li{
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px;
    position:relative;
    padding:14px 0;
}

#navi li a, .subnavi li a{
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:29px;
    padding:0 13px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:arial;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #034e9f;
    filter: dropshadow(color=#034e9f, offx=0, offy=2);
}

#navi > li:hover > a, li:hover > a , #navi li a.active{
    background:#055c9f;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px 0px #042960;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px 0px #042960;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px 0px #042960;
    border:1px solid #009ada;
    color:#f7cf00;
    line-height:27px;
    padding:0 12px;               
}

.subnavi{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    top:51px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #979395;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #979395;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #979395;
    background:#0082c8;
    border:1px solid #005890;
    padding:10px 0;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

#navi li:hover .subnavi{
    display:block;

}
#navi .subnavi li{
    margin:0;
}
#navi .subnavi li a{
    display:block;
    font-size:13px;
    padding:0 15px;
    border-radius:0;
    line-height:27px;
}
#navi .subnavi li a:hover{
    padding:0 15px;
    border-radius:0;
    border-left:0;
    border-right:0;
    line-height:25px;
}
```

[Live demo][2]******

Comment: And what about users who navigate via the keyboard?